# What is the reason to use Greenwich mean time (GMT) for world time

Tags: time, utc, gmt

What is the reason to use Greenwich mean time (GMT) for world time. Is there any reason to use Greenwich Mean Time. Please any one explain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should timestamps always use UTC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038128/should-timestamps-always-use-utc). See also [Storing DateTime (UTC) vs. storing DateTimeOffset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715620/storing-datetime-utc-vs-storing-datetimeoffset) and especially [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is because most people are used to GMT. If you're going to display information to a person, specifically time, you would want a format they can easily understand. Using GMT saves you the extra steps of converting to UTC and back.

Although, you might consider which to display to users. One format may be more familiar than another. I would typically go with UTC for global applications, and GMT for European or UK-based applications.

Comment: This misses the point. [GMT and UTC are the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612148/gmt-vs-utc-dates), to within a few seconds. The OP is asking, why use GMT/UTC, vs. local time.

Comment: I mean, why don't use India/China/Africa ... (or) other places for time zone. I don't know, this is the correct question. please explain me.

Comment: Review the links I provided above, @Visva.